# How to solve $y’ + ky^2 =c$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I’m new to non-linear differential equations. I have to solve
$$
y’ + ky^2 =c
$$
Where $k$ and $c$ are constants/parameters. I tried multiplying by $y’$ but the result was not as desired. I’m unable to find a good substitution, but I think that we got no independent variables (autonomous equation) so it might be solvable (not just numerically analysed).

Comment: I think converting it to $y^2 = \frac{c - y'}{k}$ should work.

Comment: If you know $y'$ and $y$, it should work just fine.

Comment: Even I don't know that topic !

Comment: The DE is separable.

Comment: @Aryadeva Would you point a hint as how to separate it?

Comment: yes sure I have added an answer . knight

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$y’ + ky^2 =c$$
$$y'=c-ky^2$$
I suppose $k \ne 0$ because in this case you have:
$y'=c \implies y=cx+C_1$ and you're done.
The differential eqquation is separable:
$$\int \dfrac {dy}{c-ky^2}=\int dx$$
Now it depends on the value of the constant $c$.

For example for $c=0$ you have:
$$\int \dfrac {dy}{-ky^2}=\int dx$$
$$\dfrac 1 {ky}=x+B$$
$$ky=\dfrac 1 {x+B}$$
$$y(x)=\dfrac 1{kx+A}$$
Where $A$ is a constant.

Comment: Should I leave it into this integral form? Can we analyse the behaviour of $y$ from this integral form?

Comment: You can go further ...Suppose $c=0$ integrate and suppose $c>0$ and the third case where $c<0$ and integrate @Knight It depends also on the sign of $k$

Answer (score 3):

It might be overkill, but you could also consider this equation as Riccati equation and use the associated substitution $y=\frac{u'}{ku}$ so that
$$
y'=\frac{u''}{ku}-\frac{u'^2}{ku^2}=c-k\frac{u'^2}{k^2u^2}\\
\implies u''-ck\,u=0
$$
Now this equation has well-known solutions for all the three cases of the signs (or nullity) of $ck$.

Comment: Not overkill at all...+1

Answer (score 1):

The equation is separable and autonomous. If $c\ne0$, set $\lambda=\sqrt{\left|\dfrac kc\right|}$ and write

$$\frac{dy}{1\pm\lambda^2y^2}=c\,dx.$$

Now with $z=\lambda y$,

$$\frac{dz}{1\pm z^2}=c\lambda\,dx,$$

you have one of

$$\arctan/\text{artanh}(z)=c\lambda x+c'.$$

Finally,

$$y=\sqrt{\left|\dfrac ck\right|}\tan/\tanh(\sqrt{|kc|}\,x+c').$$

The case $=0$ is easy.